# AWS Elemental Media Converter How To Create Job Thumbnail using .Net C#

Tags: c#

> AWS Elemental Media Converter How To Create Job Thumbnail using .Net C# - I am unable to create the Aws Elemental Media Converter Job using .Net C#. facing the output group exception. I have tried with preset defined facing the same issue using the code and preset...

```
createJobRequest.Role = mediaConvertRole;
createJobRequest.Queue = jobQueue;
createJobRequest.UserMetadata.Add("Customer", "Amazon");

#region Create job settings
Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.JobSettings jobSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.JobSettings();
jobSettings.AdAvailOffset = 0;
jobSettings.TimecodeConfig = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.TimecodeConfig();
jobSettings.TimecodeConfig.Source = Amazon.MediaConvert.TimecodeSource.EMBEDDED;
createJobRequest.Settings = jobSettings;

#region Thumbnail

Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.OutputGroup ofgT = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.OutputGroup();
ofgT.Name = "Thumbnail";
ofgT.OutputGroupSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.OutputGroupSettings();
ofgT.OutputGroupSettings.Type = Amazon.MediaConvert.OutputGroupType.FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS;
ofgT.OutputGroupSettings.FileGroupSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.FileGroupSettings();
ofgT.OutputGroupSettings.FileGroupSettings.Destination = fileOutput;

Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Output outputT = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Output();
outputT.NameModifier = "_thumb_00001";
outputT.Extension = "png";
output.Preset = preset_thumbnail;

#region Mp4 Container
outputT.ContainerSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.ContainerSettings();
outputT.ContainerSettings.Container = Amazon.MediaConvert.ContainerType.MP4;
Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Mp4Settings mp4T = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Mp4Settings();
mp4T.CslgAtom = Amazon.MediaConvert.Mp4CslgAtom.INCLUDE;
mp4T.FreeSpaceBox = Amazon.MediaConvert.Mp4FreeSpaceBox.EXCLUDE;
mp4T.MoovPlacement = Amazon.MediaConvert.Mp4MoovPlacement.PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD;
outputT.ContainerSettings.Mp4Settings = mp4T;
#endregion Mp4 Container

ofgT.Outputs.Add(outputT);
createJobRequest.Settings.OutputGroups.Add(ofgT);

#endregion Thumbnail

#region Input
Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Input input = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Input();
input.FilterEnable = Amazon.MediaConvert.InputFilterEnable.AUTO;
input.PsiControl = Amazon.MediaConvert.InputPsiControl.USE_PSI;
input.FilterStrength = 0;
input.DeblockFilter = Amazon.MediaConvert.InputDeblockFilter.DISABLED;
input.DenoiseFilter = Amazon.MediaConvert.InputDenoiseFilter.DISABLED;
input.TimecodeSource = Amazon.MediaConvert.InputTimecodeSource.EMBEDDED;
input.FileInput = fileInput;

Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.AudioSelector audsel = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.AudioSelector();
audsel.Offset = 0;
audsel.DefaultSelection = Amazon.MediaConvert.AudioDefaultSelection.NOT_DEFAULT;
audsel.ProgramSelection = 1;

input.AudioSelectors.Add("Audio Selector 1", audsel);

input.VideoSelector = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.VideoSelector();
input.VideoSelector.ColorSpace = Amazon.MediaConvert.ColorSpace.FOLLOW;

createJobRequest.Settings.Inputs.Add(input);

#endregion Input

Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.CreateJobResponse createJobResponse = mcClient.CreateJob(createJobRequest);
string jobId = createJobResponse.Job.Id;
```

> AWS Elemental Media Converter How To Create Job Thumbnail using .Net C#

Answer (score 0):

This Code solve my problem to generate the thumbnail using Aws elemental media converter. Passing the outoup object with these parameters:

```
Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Output outputThumb = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.Output();
outputThumb.ContainerSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.ContainerSettings { Container = Amazon.MediaConvert.ContainerType.RAW };
outputThumb.NameModifier = "_thumbnail";
outputThumb.Extension = "png";
outputThumb.VideoDescription = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.VideoDescription();
outputThumb.VideoDescription.CodecSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.VideoCodecSettings();
outputThumb.VideoDescription.CodecSettings.Codec = "FRAME_CAPTURE";
outputThumb.VideoDescription.CodecSettings.FrameCaptureSettings = new Amazon.MediaConvert.Model.FrameCaptureSettings {
  MaxCaptures = 1,
  Quality = 100
};

ofg.Outputs.Add(outputThumb);
```